# Text position moving around on different sized monitors

Tags: html, css

Here's my code:

```
<div class="swd-layout-cell layout-item-2" style="width: 100%">
    <p>
        <img width="450" height="400" alt="" src="images/new.jpg" style="float: left;margin-right:20px" class="">
    </p>
     <h5>CloudMoV</h5>

     <h6>Mobile users can import a live or on-demand video to watch from any video streaming site.&nbsp;</h6>

     <h6>Invite your friends to watch the video concurrently.&nbsp;</h6>

     <h6>Chat with your friends while enjoying the video.</h6>

    <br>
</div>
```

The image appears on the left with the text on right of it. But on different sized monitors the text placement is varying.On one monitor the placement was correct and on another the text was appearing below the image.

How can I fix this?

Comment: You can set a `min-width`. [**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/dL85G/). Its because you have the `width` set to a percentage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is being caused by `width: 100%;`.

### HTML:

```
<div class="swd-layout-cell layout-item-2" style="width: 100%;">
```

So you have this as your container, it will strech `100%` of the screen. In the demo mess around with the size of the window and you will see the text move around.

This is because when the window is lets say `500px`, the image is taking up `400px`. So your text is trying to get into `100px` worth of space.

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/dL85G/1/)

---

You can set a `min-width` that will stop the cotainer from getting to small so it will not squash the text.

### HTML:

```
<div class="swd-layout-cell layout-item-2" style="width: 100%; min-width: 700px;">
```

So here you can see we set a `min-width`, this works fine as it will just stop the container from getting to small.

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/dL85G/)

---

Another option is to use media tags. Now these are used to help design sites for all kind of resolutions.

### CSS:

```
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 1080px) {
   div {
        background: blue;
    }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 487px) and (max-width: 1079px) {
    div {
        background: green;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 487px) {
   div {
        background: red;
    }
}
```

So this is a quick demo to show you what they do. It uses the different CSS based from the size of the screen. So using this with your code can allow you to customise the layout depending on the size of the screen.

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/byH2j/6/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="swd-layout-cell layout-item-2" style="width: 100%;">
    <p style="clear:both;">
        <img alt="" src="images/new.jpg" style="float: left;margin-right:20px; width:50%; max-width:450px;" class="">
    </p>

     <h5>CloudMoV</h5>

     <h6>Mobile users can import a live or on-demand video to watch from any video streaming site.&nbsp;</h6>

     <h6>Invite your friends to watch the video concurrently.&nbsp;</h6>

     <h6>Chat with your friends while enjoying the video.</h6>
    <br>
</div>
```